# how to get anchor tag in ul li jquerymobile jquery or javascript phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, html-lists, anchor

im working in phonegap i want to count the theme of anchor tag here is my code

 i just want to count the theme b in anchor tag in li

```
<ul id='uSignUp' onclick="getlistitem()"  data-role='listview' data-inset='true' data-split-theme="d" data-theme="a">
            <li><a href='#'   rel="external">Accessing Your Needs</a>
            <a href="#" data-theme="b" id="A_an"  data-icon="check"> Accessing your needs status</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href='#' onclick="ToShowDF();"   rel="external">Develop Your Fitness</a>
            <a href="#"  data-theme="b" id="A_df"   data-icon="check"> Develop your fitness status</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href='#' onclick="ToShowPQ();"  rel="external">PAR-Q</a>
            <a href="#"  data-theme="d"  id="A_pq" data-icon="check"> PAR-Q Form</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href='#' onclick="ToShowLS();"  rel="external">Lifestyle Related Questions</a>
            <a href="#"  data-theme="d"  id="A_ls"  data-icon="check"> LifeStyle  status</a>
            </li>
           <li><a href='#' onclick="ToShowTNC();"  rel="external">Terms And Conditions</a>
            <a href="#"  data-theme="d"  id='A_Tnc' data-icon="check"> Terms and Conditions status</a>
           </li>
            <li><a href='#' onclick="ToShowIND();"  rel="external">Indemnity Declaration</a>
            <a href="#"  data-theme="d"  id='A_ind' data-icon="check"> Indemnity declaration status</a>
            </li>                
    </ul>
```

when i debug code in firebug its show me a div and an anchor tag and in anchor tag there are two span and on the second span i need that one.

can anyone help?

Comment: Sorry why the asterix in `**data-theme="b"**` ? it's some Phonegap feature? And I really don't know that you mead by saying *"count the theme"* what does it means? can you be more descriptive?

Comment: It could have been bold font - but it doesn't work in source code format.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
var countB = $('#uSignUp [data-theme="b"]').length;

alert( countB );
```

***[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hBz77/)***

Comment: plzzz check this is it right ?function getlistitem(){
    try{
             alert('test');
             var counter=0;
             var ulTag = document.getElementById('uSignUp');
    var li =ulTag.getElementsByTagName('li');
             $('#uSignUp > li > a').each(function() {
    var theme = $(this).data("theme");
    if (theme != undefined && theme == 'b') {
     //console.log($(this).data("theme"));
     count++;
    }
   })
   alert(count);​
         }
      }
      catch(e){alert(e);}

Comment: function getlistitem(){
    try{
             alert('test');
             var counter=0;
             var ulTag = document.getElementById('uSignUp');
    var li =ulTag.getElementsByTagName('li');
             $('#uSignUp > li > a').each(function() {
    var theme = $(this).data("theme");
    if (theme != undefined && theme == 'b') {
     //console.log($(this).data("theme"));
     count++;
    }
   })
   alert(count);​
         }
      }
      catch(e){alert(e);}

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = 0;
$('#uSignUp > li > a').each(function() {
    var theme = $(this).data("theme");
    if (theme != undefined && theme == 'b') {
        //console.log($(this).data("theme"));
        count++;
    }
})

alert(count);​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Qrjkh/)

Comment: " **data-theme="b"** " its by mistake its just as data-theme="b" i want to count the data theme on alert

Comment: function getlistitem(){ try{ alert('test'); var counter=0; var ulTag = document.getElementById('uSignUp'); var li =ulTag.getElementsByTagName('li'); $('#uSignUp > li > a').each(function() { var theme = $(this).data("theme"); if (theme != undefined && theme == 'b') { //console.log($(this).data("theme")); count++; } }) alert(count);​ } } its my JS code plzz review it